# Can pg_stat_statements.max increase cause problems?

Tags: postgresql, pg-stat-statements

My production postgresql v11 db is "tenant" over schemas, so on each schema the objects are repeated so I have over 100k objects to track with pg_stat_statements, which is set 5000 by default. If I increase this number could cause me some overheads, bottlenecks, etc..

Answer (score 1):

The only effect is that the extension creates a bigger shared memory segment at server start – memory that may be missing elsewhere.